# Is it possible to integrate Exoplayer in a webview app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am trying to build an e-commerce app for android tv. After doing some research I figured out that simplest way would be to use WebView, enable javascript and  use webchromeclient for the naigation and it worked.

I have set the url of my app to webview and moreover using javascript I am able to achieve the required navigation as well.

My issue is that my html5 app has a video tag that plays the video. **I need to use Exoplayer for playing the video for HLS**. I have downloaded the demo exoplayer app from github and it runs fine.My question is how can I **integrate Exoplayer to my app**.

**How can I call Exoplayer to my webview app that loads an html5 and javascript** based app.

While researching further I found that we can call android methods from javascript and vice-versa using javascriptinterface but I am not able to figure out how to integrate Exoplayer with my app.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a answer to this?